# How to group project results by Taxonomy Terms

Tags: orchardcms

I have a ContentType Animal which has a Taxonomy field species.
look at this posthttp://orchardpros.net/tickets/10636  and (http://www.ideliverable.com/blog/ways-to-render-lists-of-things) for a good explanation.
I runed the code,but It have 2 erro.
1.var speciesField = item.Animal.Species;----gave erro: CS1061 ,"Orchard.ContentManagement.ContentItem' does not contain a definition Animal".
2.var items = speciesDictionary[speciesTerm];----gave erro:CS0136 " A local or parameter named 'items' cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local.
please  help!

```
@using Orchard.ContentManagement
@using Orchard.Taxonomies.Models

@{

    var items = ((IEnumerable<ContentItem>)Model.ContentItems);

    var speciesDictionary = new Dictionary<TermPart, IList<ContentItem>>();


    // Collect categories and their items.
    foreach (var item in items) {

        var speciesField = item.Animal.Species; // Assumes that the species field is attached to the Animal type's implicit part (Animal).
        var speciesTerms = (IEnumerable<TermPart>)speciesField.Terms;

        foreach (var speciesTerm in speciesTerms) {
            var list = speciesDictionary.ContainsKey(speciesTerm) ? speciesDictionary[speciesTerm] : default(IList<ContentItem>);

            if (list == null) {
                list = new List<ContentItem>();
                speciesDictionary.Add(speciesTerm, list);
            }

            list.Add(item);
        }
    }
}
<ul>
    @foreach (var speciesTerm in speciesDictionary.Keys) {
        var items = speciesDictionary[speciesTerm];
        <li>
           @speciesTerm.Name


        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Your first error indicates that you are trying to get a property of the `ContentItem` class which does not exist. This is actually partially correct, because it does exist on the ContentItem, but because you cast it to a ContentItem class, it loses the dynamic properties.
   You can fix this by not casting to a ContentItem class, but just to dynamic:

   ```
   var items = ((IEnumerable<dynamic>)Model.ContentItems);
   ```
2. The second error indicates that you are trying to create a variable while it already exists. This is obvious, because in the top of your .cshtml you already have `items` defined:

   ```
   @{
       // var items is defined here, you can not redefine it
       // as always in C#
       var items = ((IEnumerable<ContentItem>)Model.ContentItems);
   }
   ```

   So instead give it a different name in the bottom:

   ```
   <ul>
       @foreach (var speciesTerm in speciesDictionary.Keys) {
           // Cannot use 'items' here again
           var speciesItems = speciesDictionary[speciesTerm];
           <li>
              @speciesTerm.Name
           </li>
       }
   </ul>
   ```

Comment: devqon, sory! I  rely  later,  I   modify  code by your  advice, It has  a  erro:This  line  "list.Add(item);"------gave erro:"Add" not  definition .

Comment: I also  modify code,From  to group project results by Taxonomy Terms

to group project results by tags.post here<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43771687/how-to-group-project-results-by-tags>